# Angular JS: Perform DOM manipulation after modal dialog is closed

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS. I have set up a plunker to demonstrate the situation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/P90BIfQRcnh1xTX0xqWT?p=preview

On the modal dialog gets closed, I need to show the span next to the continue button. How should I proceed?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to the plunk to make it work:

1. Get rid of `ng-controller` in modal.html, since you've binded `ModalController` to `<body>` already
2. Add a model called "done" to scope i.e. `$scope.done = false`
3. Use `ng-show="done"` in the "Work completed" span, so the span's shown/hidden states are determined by the "done" model
4. In your `model.continue()`, set "done" to true to show the "Work completed" span

Updated plunk is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DRvXlRP2UOwGaxHjcrfN

Comment: Appreciate jaux, for taking out time to reply.